# Visual Studio 2015 Setup Blocked

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2015

I get at Setup Blocked trying to install VS 2015 on win 7 x64

[image: Setup Blocked]

I had a CTP version installed, but I have uninstalled it, ran a reg clean, manual search and removed any key with vs 2015 or version=14, but stil I get this error. :-(

from the log file:

> Condition 'CurrentOperation = "Install" AND (CommunityCore_Version14 <
>   v14.0.23104.0) AND (ProfessionalCore_Version14 > v0.0.0.0) AND
>   (ProfessionalCore_Version14 < v14.0.23104.0) AND
>   NOT(ProfessionalCore_Version14 = v14.0.23107.0) AND
>   (UltimateCore_Version14 =  v0.0.0.0)' evaluates to **true**.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and downloaded the old CTP, installed it again and uninstalled it using the /uninstall /force flags

it solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/942fd4f7-9085-4cbf-bb98-a58706dbb693/visual-studio-ultimate-2012-rc-setup-blocked

1. first Open registry (as administrator) and browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
2. See if there is a string value "PendingFileRenameOperations" and check the value
3. If there is one, Rename the string value "PendingFileRenameOperations" to something similar to "PendingFileRenameOperationsrename"
4. After restarting the machine, the uninstall should work fine.
5. Then change the registration key back to its original value.