# Install Visual Studio 2015 express on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450972/cannot-install-visual-studio-2015-community-on-windows-7), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346692/microsoft-visual-studio-setup-blocked), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588676/visual-studio-2015-setup-blocked), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372725/microsoft-visual-studio-professional-2015-setup-blocked) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003203/install-visual-studio-2015-community-edition-on-windows-7) questions and answers, none of them have help me at all.

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Express or Community edition, I have W7 SP1, I have tried with admin rights, I've checked that no preview VS have been installed but no matter what I do, I still can't install VS and I don't understand what the log says, I'll append a picture and what I think is an important part of the log file:

[image]

```bash
[0D48:1794][2015-10-20T19:36:45]i000: MUX:  Feed uri to register: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=558779&clcid=0x409
[0D48:1794][2015-10-20T19:36:47]e000: MUX:  Exception: Info: Unable to load dynamic feed
[0D48:1794][2015-10-20T19:36:47]e000: MUX:  ERROR: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
[0D48:1794][2015-10-20T19:36:47]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.Util.IsSignatureValid(String xmlFile)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.LoadFromXml(String xmlFile, Boolean loadEnclosures, Boolean isOnlineFeedLoaded, Boolean verifySignature)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.Load(Uri productFileUrl, Boolean filterByArchitectureAndOS, Boolean loadEnclosures, Boolean useCachedVersion, String cacheDirectory, Architecture architecture, Int32 osType, String& finalFeedCacheLocation, Boolean& isOnlineFeedLoaded, Boolean& onlineFeedLoadError, String localFeed, Boolean verifySignature, String feedUri, String lastUsedFeedLocationKey, BundleProperties currentBundle)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.Load(Uri productFileUrl, Boolean filterByArchitectureAndOS, Boolean loadEnclosures, Boolean useCachedVersion, String cacheDirectory, String& finalFeedCacheLocation, Boolean& isOnlineFeedLoaded, Boolean& onlineFeedLoadError, String localFeed, Boolean verifySignature, String feedUri, String lastUsedFeedLocationKey, BundleProperties currentBundle)
   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.Utility.SecondaryInstallerUtility.LoadProductManager()
[0D48:05C8][2015-10-20T19:36:54]i000: MUX:  View loaded
[0D48:05C8][2015-10-20T19:36:54]i000: MUX:  Go to Blocker page.
[0D48:05C8][2015-10-20T19:36:54]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
```

Apparently, the problem is in:

```bash
Could not load file or assembly 
     'System.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
      PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

**UPDATE**

After *devlin carnate* suggestion and reading answers from [this site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49f51101-9769-4ba6-8ab5-ec99debac917/visual-studio-installation-fails-with-cannot-load-systemsecurity?forum=vssetup) and [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a8c09bf0-9b82-416e-90f8-05f3d5cdb90a/vs2015-community-setup-crashes?forum=vssetup) too I have tried the following:

- **Update my OS**. Except for the "update to W10" I have installed all updates (even some of those marked as *optionals*).
- **Run a "scan now" from command prompt**, bassically, I followed instructions from [this site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833), and even when something were marked as *corrupted* I don't know how to repair it ('cause no dll or file were detected).
- **Uninstall the .NET Framework and install a prev version** (from 4.5 to 4) but the problem persist (also, after this, windows suggest to update to 4.5 so I reinstall 4.5 version).
- **Use the [.NET Framework Repair Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135)** with no results.

**UPDATE 2**

I just format my HDD unit and reinstall (the same) W7 SP1 all over again, after that, I was able to install VS Community Edition, but I don't take this as a solution since is just too drastic and I don't know the original reason of why this happened in the first place.

Comment: [This site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49f51101-9769-4ba6-8ab5-ec99debac917/visual-studio-installation-fails-with-cannot-load-systemsecurity?forum=vssetup) seems to indicate that you need to do windows updates, including drivers.  Perhaps that's worth a shot.

Comment: @devlincarnate when you say "update", can I just update everything without update my windows to w10? (I just don't want to change to another windows) thank for the link, I'll check all my drivers

Comment: Yes, that thread seems to suggest you should apply any pending Windows Updates, including drivers.  From what I read, that doesn't involve updating your OS version.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @phobos2077 at the end, I was so exhausted that I just formatted my HDD unit and re-install windows 7 SP1 again, after that, I was able to install visual studio (but I don't think that count as a solution since is too drastic)